# Problem with the Google Drive API I not found the client_id and client_secret

Tags: java, api

I have a problem with the Google Drive API.

I'm implementing the example of this page: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-java

But, I don't know my CLIENT_ID and my CLIENT_SECRET.
In my developers console page I see this CLIENT_ID. As you can see in the image.
[image: Google Developers Console]

The CLIENT_ID of the image is the correct CLIENT_ID that I need to put in the code?
And, if it's correct, where is my CLIENT_SECRET?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The CLIENT_SECRET is in the JSON.